# How to exchange words in a filename using the shell?

Tags: shell, sed, grep, rename

One of my customers is a school. On their file server all projects have a directory with the same naming scheme.

```
<last name>, <first name> <second name>? - <project description>
```

For example:

```
Miller, John Andrew - Long project description
Willis, Bruce - Description, perhaps with comma
Lewis, Mary-Jane - Description - Including minus
```

The new naming convention is:

```
<first name> <second name>? <last name> - <project description>
```

For example:

```
John Andrew Miller - Long project description
Bruce Willis - Description, perhaps with comma
Mary-Jane Lewis - Description - Including minus
```

Now how to batch rename all existing folders to the new convention?

Comment: Take a look at this tool: `rename`

Comment: You can name such as output of date format, it help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the description part of the filename can contain the pattern `-` (a hyphen between two spaces), you can change that to some symbol that *doesn't* occur in the description part. I chose `£`, but that's purely arbitrary.

```
rename 's/ - /£/' *
rename 's/([^,]*), ([^£]*)£/$2 $1 - /' *
```

`s/ - /£/' tells rename to replace the first instance of` - `it finds with`£`. The second command is a bit more complicated. Parenthases (`()`) are used to group selections together -- so everything that matches the pattern within the first set of parens can be called later as`$1`(all the way up to`$9`).`[^,]`means 'any character, except for`,`';`*`means 'zero or more of the previous character';`[^,]*` means 'zero or more of any character except for a comma'. Since rename is greedy by default, it matches the longest string possible.

The rest, I think, follows pretty naturally.

If you're not sure whether a symbol appears anywhere in the filename, just run:

```
printf '%s\n' *£*
```

---

If you have perl-rename:

```
rename 's/([^,]*), (.*) - /$2 $1 - /' *
```

This will break if the description part of the filenames contain `-` (that is, a `-` between two spaces).

You should test this with the `-n` flag, which won't rename any files, but will show what it *would* have done:

```
rename -n 's/([^,]*), (.*) - /$2 $1 - /' *
```

Comment: As I remember there are files which contain a minus between two spaces in the description part.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the matching is concerned, you'd need to be quite careful in order to build anything robust. For example, assuming that the first and middle names

1. must start with a letter
2. may contain hyphens (but no other punctuation or whitespace)

your given-name pattern becomes something like `[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]-]*`. You can then make an optional space-separated middle name as `((?: [[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]-]*)?)` where the extra non-capturing group structure just helps to keep the capture group numbers straight when the middle name is empty. Putting it together for example using the perl-based rename command

```
rename -nv -- 's/(^[^,]*), ([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]-]*)((?: [[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]-]*)?)/$2$3 $1/' *
```

or (allowing for more general whitespace between the fields instead of single spaces)

```
rename -nv -- 's/(^[^,]*),\s+([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]-]*)((?:\s+[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]-]*)?)/$2$3 $1/' *
```

The `-n` switch is a no-op i.e. it won't actually perform the renames until removed. If you don't have the perl-based rename you could use a combination of `perl` and `mv`.